# How to add scroll bar to responsive html page

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, overflow

How can I add scroll bar to a table?
I have read the thread about adding the table to a div and CSS the div with `overflow:scroll` but then when I scroll down table head disappears... 
Also I want my page to be responsive (I'm using bootstrap) and the table rows come from a mysql database. Using the CSS `position:fixed` also mess up my table head..

Is there another way?

My jsp:

```
<table class="inflow-table ">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div th-div-first">ID</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Όνομα</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Προιόν</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Κατάσταση</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Ύψος<div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div" >Gross</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Net</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Θερμ. °C</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Στάθμη Προιόντος</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Στάθμη Νερού</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Ειδ. Βάρος</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="button black th-div">Μέγιστη Ροή</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div></div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <c:forEach items="${TankState}" var="state">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div td-div-first">${state.getTank().getTankID()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getTank().getTankName()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getTank().getProduct().getProductName()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getStatusDescription()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getTank().getTankHeight()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getGross()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getNet()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getTemperature()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 my-bar">${state.getProductLevel()}m</div>
                                    <div class="progress my-bar ">
                                        <%  
                                            out.write("<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-danger' style='width:");
                                        %>${state.getProductLevelPercentance()}<%  out.write("%'></div>" ); %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getWaterLevel()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getProductDensity()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div">${state.getTank().getMaxFlow()}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="td-div td-div-last" onclick="setValue(${state.getTank().getTankID()});"> >> </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code so that we can get a lead